# Unzip a file using ZipArchive in iOS sdk

Tags: iphone, ios, unzip

I am using the following code to unzip a file using ZipArchive :

```
NSString *zipDirectoryName = [sourceURL.lastPathComponent substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(0, sourceURL.lastPathComponent.length - sourceURL.pathExtension.length - 1)];
NSString *zipDirectoryPath = [documentDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:zipDirectoryName];
NSLog(@"Unzipping file at path  %@", zipDirectoryPath);

success = [zip UnzipFileTo:zipDirectoryPath overWrite:YES];
if (!success) {
    NSLog(@"Failed to unzip the zip file");
    return;
}
else {
    NSLog(@"Done");  
}
```

But i get "Failed to unzip the zip file". Can't figure out why file is not being Unzipped. Any help would be appreciated

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Refer this link, please be sure that u followed all steps correctly .Personally i think ur code should work: 
`http://www.icodeblog.com/2012/08/13/unzipping-files-using-zip-archive/`

Have you used this :`ZipArchive *za = [[ZipArchive alloc] init];
`

Comment: Adding more code (how you open the archive) and `NSLog` output would be very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, use zip delegate to listen to error messages

```
@interface MyClass : NSObject <ZipArchiveDelegate>
...
@end
```

```
@implementation MyClass

- (void)ErrorMessage:(NSString*)msg {
    NSLog(@"Zip error message: \"%@\"", msg);
}

- (void)doSomething {
   ...

   zip.delegate = self;
   [zip UnzipFileTo:zipDirectoryPath overWrite:YES]

   ...
}

@end
```

If you know the error message, you can check the reason of the fail. However, common problems would be that the archive or the target directory don't exist or you don't have the permissions to write there.

Answer (score 0):

Download  SSZip from [Here](https://github.com/soffes/ssziparchive)
and then use SSZipArchive as :

```
- (void)UnzippingZipFile {

    NSArray  *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *outputPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"/FolderName"];

    NSString *filePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@", documentsDirectory,@"ZipFile.zip"];
    NSString *zipPath = filePath;

    [SSZipArchive unzipFileAtPath:zipPath toDestination:outputPath delegate:self];

}
```

Hope it helps you.

Comment: Why use SSZip? Wont, ZipArchive work? Is there some issue with zipArchive?

Comment: I have used SSZipArchive many times. and it works fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
-(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation
{
    if (url != nil && [url isFileURL]) {
        FileNameStr = [url.lastPathComponent substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(0, url.lastPathComponent.length - url.pathExtension.length - 1)];
    }
}

- (void)unzipAndSaveFile{

    NSString*EpubFile=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@.epub",[self applicationDocumentsDirectory],FileNameStr];

    ZipArchive* za = [[ZipArchive alloc] init];

    if( [za UnzipOpenFile:EpubFile] ){

        NSString *strPath=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/Unzipped/%@",[self applicationDocumentsDirectory],FileNameStr];

        //Delete all the previous files
        NSFileManager *filemanager=[[NSFileManager alloc] init];
        if ([filemanager fileExistsAtPath:strPath]) {

            [filemanager removeItemAtPath:strPath error:&error];
        }

        [filemanager release];
        filemanager=nil;

        //start unzip
        BOOL ret = [za UnzipFileTo:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/",strPath] overWrite:YES];

        if( NO==ret ){
            // error handler here
            UIAlertView *alert=[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error"
                                                          message:@"An unknown error occured"
                                                         delegate:self
                                                cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                                otherButtonTitles:nil];
            [alert show];

            [alert release];

            alert=nil;
        }

        [za UnzipCloseFile];
    }

    [za release];
}
- (NSString *)applicationDocumentsDirectory {
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *basePath = ([paths count] > 0) ? [paths objectAtIndex:0] : nil;
NSLog(@"basePath:%@",basePath);
return basePath;}
```

Comment: ya.. maybe u correct... bt don't knw why it doesn't work for me :(